# Совместить 2 массива в один

Tags: php

Нужно совместить 2 массива в один таким образом чтобы в первом массиве были заменены только те ключи которые присутствуют в массиве 2 или добавлены.То есть нужно заменить DB1 и добавить DB4.DB 2 и 3 не трогать.Подскажите как лучше сделать.

```
Array1 = array(
    'databases' =>  array(
        array(
            'name' => 'DB1',
            'tables' => array(
                array('name' => 'table1'),
                array('name' => 'table2'),
                array('name' => 'table3'),

            )
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'DB2',
            'tables' => array(
                array('name' => 'table1'),
                array('name' => 'table2'),
                array('name' => 'table3'),

            )
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'DB3',
            'tables' => array(
                array('name' => 'table1'),
                array('name' => 'table2'),
                array('name' => 'table3'),

            )
        )
    )
);



Array2 = array(
    'databases' =>  array(
        array(
            'name' => 'DB1',
            'tables' => array(
                array('name' => 'table1'),
                array('name' => 'table2'),
                array('name' => 'table3'),

            )
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'DB4',
            'tables' => array(
                array('name' => 'table1'),
                array('name' => 'table2'),
                array('name' => 'table3'),

            )
        ),
    )
);



foreach($fileConfig['databases'] as $key => $val){

    foreach($filteredConfig as $confKey => $confVal){
        if($val['name'] == $confVal['name']){
            $fileConfig['databases'][$key] = $confVal;
        } else{
            $fileConfig['databases'][] = $confVal;
        }
    }
}
```

Мой вариант не подошел так как кроме как замены массива происходит и добавление одних и тех же постоянно.Как контролировать существование уже данного ключа?

Придется действительно переделать массив чтобы ключами являлись имена бд и тогда применить

```
foreach($config2['databases'] as $db => $val){
            if(array_key_exists($db, $config['databases'])){
                $config['databases'][$db] = $val;
            }else{
                $config['databases'][$db][] = $val;
            }
        }
```

Comment: а были бы `name` ключами, и проблемы бы не было никакой, да?

Comment: Верно, но это на крайний случай.При данной структуре какие варианты есть?

Comment: дак вы данную структуру к нужной приведите, решите вопрос, а потом замените ключи обратно, если уж это так требуется

Comment: спасибо вижу действительно с измененной структурой будет гораздо проще

Comment: Зачем переделывать? можно сделать иначе. Просто перебирайте массив, и сравнивайте первый элемент подмассива, если он подходит под условие, то сравнивайте через array_diff  подмассив tables, если он отличается то производите обновление или другие действия которые вам нужны

Comment: почему именно первый?

Comment: @mydls1 можно сделать сложно, а можно просто. переборы массивов за n^2 это сложно. а линейные ключи это куда проще. В целом, когда имя уникально, то само собой напрашивается как ключ для доступа к данным

Comment: @quaresma89 в целом много переделывать ведь не надо. добавить только ключи, пусть `name` внутри тоже остается.

Comment: Так и сделал спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Возможно я не правильно интепретировал ваш вопрос
Но если вам нужно слить два массива, с условием обновления значений при их сущестовании, то есть встроенная функция [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php) ( меняете последовательность параметров, что переписовался нужный массив )
Хочу отметить, что функция сравнивает сами значения, что вам собственно и нужно.

Структура то у вас одинаковаяя

Я девано решал подобную задачу с помощью данной функции.   Так же обратите вние на функцию [array_intersect_assoc](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-intersect-assoc.php)
Но мне кажется я вас гдето не допонял....

Comment: В моем случае не совсем подойдет функция array_merge, во первых у меня ключи не являются именем бд,

Comment: Ну еще пару раз перечитал ваш вопрос, вы могли бы его уточнить?  или расширить